How to account for domain when solving inequalities in exponential functions
I'm struggling with the following question from an algebra exam from the 1970s.
The function f is defined as follows: $f(x) = \frac{3^{x+1} + 1}{3^x-1}$.
a) Solve the inequality $f(x) < 5$
b) For which values of $p$ and $x$ does the following hold: $f(x) + f(-x) = p$
For a) I worked the exponential inequality and got to $x > 1$. However, inspection of the graph shows that $f(x) < 5$ also when $x < 0$. How can I show that $x < 0$ and $x > 1$ together make up the correct answer? 

b) Given that the limit at positive infinity is 3 and the limit at negative infinity is -1, you could argue that p goes towards 2 when x tends towards infinity. But I feel I am cheating my way around some more analytical work. Am I interpreting the question correctly?

For the second part, why don't we just add them,
$$\frac{3^{1+x}+1}{3^x-1}+\frac{3^{1-x}+1}{3^{-x}-1}=p \
\implies\frac{3^{1+x}+1}{3^x-1}+\frac{3+3^x}{1-3^x}=p \
\implies 2\frac{3^x-1}{3^x-1}=p \implies p=2$$  Hmm I don't understand the concept from your limits, but it seems to be correct. Can you explain a bit to me?

By determining how simple functions behave at +/- infinity, calculus reasons about how more complex function behave at infinity. Looking at the fraction in the original function, we know that the nominator will grow very large, just like the denominator. Both the +1 and -1 term in nominator and denominator will become irrelevant for the size of the nominator and the denominator. Now, since the nominator is 3^(x+1) it will always be exactly three times at large as the denominator. Therefore, the whole fraction will approach the value of 3 at pos. infinity, and you reason similarly for neg. inf

Could you give me a hint/ solution on how you simplified from the second to the third line?

I suspect that your first step was multiplying both sides of the inequality by $3^x - 1$.
And I also suspect that when you did that, for failed to account for the possibility that $3^x-1$ is negative.
You have to break your proof into two cases:
Case 1: $3^x - 1 > 0$, equivalently $x > 0$. When you multiply both sides of the inequality by $3^x-1$, the direction of the inequality is unchanged.
Case 2: $3^x - 1 < 0$, equivalently $x<0$. When you mulitply both sides of the inequality by $3^x-1$, the direction of the inequality changes.

I'm writing as a solution because you requested it in the comments :)
$$\frac{3^{1+x}+1}{3^x-1}+\frac{3^{1-x}+1}{3^{-x}-1}=p \\ \implies\frac{3^{1+x}+1}{3^x-1}+\frac{3+3^x}{1-3^x}=p \\ \implies 
\frac{3×3^x+1-3-3^x}{3^x-1}=p\\\implies2\frac{3^x-1}{3^x-1}=p \implies p=2
$$
Only if $x≠\log_31$
